# How to tell cloud-init to only run userdata script?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, cloud-init

I'm making a custom ami to use in CloudFormation template and hence I don't need any of cloud-init functionality except running user-data script I provide in CFN template. How do I configure cloud-init to only run that script on instance boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cloud formation scripts, like cfn-init, must be called from UserData to start.  If you don't want to use them, just don't call them.  If you want, you can uninstall them from your image (if they're even present).  [AWS Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html)